# getting an entire row as an output where certain column has max value using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

Am new to python-pandas. I need some help in getting the entire row as output, rather than one column. Example: 
df1.max() is giving me this output.

Charge_Per_Line    263566.10

but i need output as:

claim_number      charge_per_line

3                  263566.10

Thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one columns `DataFrame` need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and select last row by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'claim_number':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 
                   'Charge_Per_Line':[10,5,4,20,10,3]})
print (df)
   Charge_Per_Line  claim_number
0               10             1
1                5             1
2                4             2
3               20             2
4               10             3
5                3             3

df1 = df.groupby('claim_number').sum()
print (df1)
              Charge_Per_Line
claim_number                 
1                          15
2                          24
3                          13

res = df1.sort_values('Charge_Per_Line').iloc[[-1]]
#alternative solution
#res = df1.loc[[df1['Charge_Per_Line'].idxmax()], ['Charge_Per_Line']]
print (res)
              Charge_Per_Line
claim_number                 
2                          24
```

If want column from `index`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('claim_number', as_index=False).sum()
print (df1)
   claim_number  Charge_Per_Line
0             1               15
1             2               24
2             3               13

res = df1.sort_values('Charge_Per_Line').iloc[[-1]]
#alternative
#res = df1.loc[[df1['Charge_Per_Line'].idxmax()]]
print (res)
   claim_number  Charge_Per_Line
1             2               24
```